# How do I phonebook contact which also have group making facilities and image containing facilities

Tags: java, android

I want to make address book application in android which can have Name,phone No, email id, also have images. it also have the group making facilities.
I am new to android please help.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Content Provider class you can see a examaple of that in
[Contact Manager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html)